# PHP create array from database using size of another array as counter for for loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code. The first part retrieves a multidimensional array from the database.

```
$model = $product->getModelsBikes();
echo "<pre>".print_r($model, true)."</pre>";
```

Its structure is like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [manufacture] => data
            [name] => data
            [code] => data
            [cc] => data
            [bike_type] => data
            [title] => data
            [about] => data
        )

    [1] =>; Array
        (
            [manufacture] => data
            [name] => data
            [code] => data
            [cc] => data
            [bike_type] => data
            [title] => data
            [about] => data
        )

        ....
```

Second part

```
$count = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($model); $i++) {
    $modelSpecs = $product->getModelSpecs($model[$i]['code']);
    $count++;
}
```

With this code i am trying to create another array of content based on the product code. however its just overriding the data in the array with each pass until only the last set is stored in the array because its a for loop.

This has got my stumped and is probably obvious but how would i iterate through and create another array exactly like the first but with the new data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this. This will make $modelSpecs an array and add the getModelSpecs return to the end of the array each iteration

```
$modelSpecs[] = $product->getModelSpecs($model[$i]['code']);
```

you should also probably define the array before the loop like this

```
$modelSpecs=array();
```

Comment: Thank you sir, thats perfect. Ill mark this when i can :) Thanks.